# top CPU load vs CPU Load telemetry in JProfiler

Tags: java, cpu, jprofiler

I have a sample application that simply runs `CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> { while (true) {} });`

looking at the cpu usage with top, i see the expected 100%. [top screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miCgT.png).

inspecting the process with JProfiler, i see a CPU Load of 10 to 20%.
[jprofiler CPU Load telemetry screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WMDa.png).

I have 8 physical cores on my machine. Does this mean that i see the overall system load? this would give me around 100/8 cores = 12.5%. can someone confirm this?

The load sometimes goes up to 18%, is this the side effect caused by jprofiler?

thanks for you help

Comment: What OS?  On Linux for example, the convention is that 100% CPU usage means on average 1 core is fully busy, and 800% would be all 8 cores.  But on Windows, the convention for the OS's normal resource-monitor tools is that 100% is *all* cores busy, so 1 thread running an infinite loop is 12.5%.  You can test this with an ever simpler infinite loop, without runAsync(), just a tiny program that does `while(true){}` in `main`.

Comment: I'm observing this on Linux and Mac

Comment: It's clear to me what "top" does. My question is, what do I see in JProfiler?

Answer (score 1):

JProfiler reports the values returned by the MBean `com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean`.

A value of 100% means that all CPUs were actively running threads from the JVM 100% of the time during the recent period being observed. Threads from the JVM include the application threads as well as the JVM internal threads.

In the screen shot, it looks like the JVM has detected 16 cores, one of which is fully used by the JVM. The variations in the system load can be due to multiple factors. If you are running the JProfiler GUI on the same machine, it is one of those factors.

Comment: Thanks Ingo. That was very helpful. How do you see it‘s 16 cores?

Comment: By the percentage of the process load

Comment: Merci beaucoup!